# Add module to custom compiled PHP

Tags: php5, centos6, php

In CentOS I have a compiled version of PHP but it is missing IMAP module. Is it possible to add that module without re-compiling php?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just download the source of your current version, untar it, go the the ext/imap directory of the untared source then run:

```
phpize
./configure
make
```

You might need to run ./configure with some options specifiying the imap libraries used like:

```
  --with-imap=DIR       Include IMAP support. DIR is the c-client install prefix
  ...
  --with-imap-ssl=DIR     IMAP: Include SSL support. DIR is the OpenSSL install prefix
```

After you compiled the module you should located it under ext/imap/modules, it should be named imap.so like ext/imap/modules/imap.so. You need to move this further to the extension_dir directory that you can get by running `php -i | grep extension_dir` or by createing a php file that will say `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and run it from the web interface after which search for extension_dir on the result page.

After you've moved the module file you'll need to add a line in the php.ini file(or create an .ini file in the additional .ini files directory) that will say:

```
extension=imap.so
```

After that you'll need to restart your web-server or php-fpm service in case you're using php-fpm.